# Doctrine OneToOne with 2 conditions on different tables

Tags: php, orm, doctrine-orm

I am working on a legacy system, that I am trying to slowly bring up to date with more modern practices.

I am trying to implement Doctrine ORM and map some existing database tables. Unfortunately changing the DB structure at this point is not feasible, so I have to work with what I've got.

Here's the DB structure:

foo:

- id
- title

bar:

- id
- foo_id
- baz_id

baz

- id
- foo_id
- bar_id
- column_value_i_want

So each `Foo` has multiple `Bar` items. This relationship is simple and works as expected. The problem is for each of those `Bar` items, there should be 1 `Baz` item, under the condition `Baz.foo_id = Foo.id AND Baz.bar_id = Bar.id)`

I have search around a bit and can't find a way to map this. Is it even possible with Doctrine?

```
 class Foo
 {
     /**
     * @Id @GeneratedValue @Column(type="integer")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @OneToMany(targetEntity="Bar", mappedBy="foo")
     */
     private $bar;

 }
```

-

```
class Bar
 {
     /**
     * @Id @GeneratedValue @Column(type="integer")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @ManyToOne(targetEntity="Foo", inversedBy="bar")
     * @JoinColumn(name="foo_id", referencedColumnName="id")
     */
    private $foo;

    //how do I get a single Baz here where (Baz.foo_id = this Foo.id AND Baz.bar_id = Bar.id)?
 }
```

-

```
class Baz
 {
     /**
     * @Id @GeneratedValue @Column(type="integer")
     */
    private $id;

    //?
    private $foo_id;

    //?
    private $bar_id;
 }
```

Comment: `foo_id` property on `Baz` seems redundant... have you tried removing that from both the DB and the class?

Comment: @MatteoTassinari It is a little redundant, but as I said this is a legacy system and I can't change the schema at the moment. I am trying to introduce Doctrine slowly using what I've got. The way the data is setup in `Baz` means it currently needs a combination of `Foo.id` and `Bar.id`, even though `Bar` is related to `Foo` already

Answer (score 0):

You must use query builder to force this limitation on the result of bar.

```
    $qry = $this->entManager->getRepository("Entities\Bar")->createQueryBuilder("Bar");
    $qry->Join("Entities\Baz", "Baz", "WITH", "Baz.id = Bar.id");
    $qry->where(Bar.foo is not null and  Baz.bar_id = Bar.id);
```

I wish this could help.